# Dynamic Menu System

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I am working on a dynamic menu system as the site I'm build has a strict naming convention.

For example, if I have a script are named `AboutUs.php`, then '**About Us**' will be a Parent Menu Item. However if I have a script named `Product.Product1.php` then '**Product**' is the Parent Item with '**Product1**' as the Sub Menu Item.

The idea is to loop through grabbing all the scripts in my frontend folder and build an array so the ul/li elements can be echoed using a nested `foreach`

I just can't seem to get the `Array` and the `$submenu)` just right.. Thanks!

```
if ($handle = opendir('frontend/')) {
while(false !== ($sFile = readdir($handle))) {
    if (strrpos($sFile, ".php") === strlen($sFile)-strlen(".php")) {
        $pos1 = strrpos($sFile, ".");
        $menu = substr($sFile, 0, $pos1);
        $pos2 = strrpos($sFile, ".php");
        if ($pos1 == $pos2) { // "." and ".php" where in the pos, skip submenu
            $links[$menu] = 'fontend/'.$sFile;
        } else {
            $submenu = substr($sFile, $pos1, $pos2);
            $links[$menu][$submenu] = 'fontend/'.$sFile;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: One thing I've been wondering about: Do the parents all have their own scripts? Using your example, would there be a `Product.php` as well as a `Product.Product1.php`? If so, there could be issues with the submenu arrays.

Comment: no we're safe there.. good call though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you might be better off exploding on '.' instead of using strpos and regex.

```
while(false !== ($sFile = readdir($handle))) {
    if (strrpos($sFile, ".php") === strlen($sFile)-strlen(".php")) {
        $parts = explode('.', $sFile);
        if (count($parts) == 2)
        {
            $urls[$parts[0]] = 'frontend/'.$sFile;
        }
        else if (count($parts) == 3)
        {
            $urls[$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = 'frontend/'.$sFile;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that would produce a much more elegant solution.

Comment: Heh, no problem. Always glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($handle = opendir('frontend/')) {
while(false !== ($sFile = readdir($handle))) {
    if (strrpos($sFile, ".php") === strlen($sFile)-strlen(".php")) {
        $posExt = strrpos($sFile, "." );
        $menu = substr($sFile, 0, $pos1);
        $posSub = strrpos($menu, ".");
        if ($posSub === false) { // "." and ".php" where in the pos, skip submenu
            $urls[$menu] = 'fontend/'.$sFile;
        } else {
            $submenu = substr($menu, $posSub, ($posExt-$posSub));
            $urls[$menu][$submenu] = 'fontend/'.$sFile;
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it, though, but it should work. ^^

EDIT:
Fixed but in getting the $submenu. It's not unlikely to be a "off-by-1" error somewhere as well.